# binding to data scoped inside jquery ready(), but outside knockout model

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind `select` elements in my view using arrays with arbitrary data which are defined *outside* my model, but *inside* jquery's `ready()` function:

```
<select data-bind='options: itemsList,                                      
                   value: selectedItem'>
</select>


 $(document).ready(function($) {
    var itemsList = ["one", "two", "three"];

    function ViewModel() {
      var self = this;      
      self.selectedItem = ko.observable();   
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

This doesn't work since `itemsList` is scoped outside the model, but inside `ready()`, making it inaccessible to the view's `select` element.

I could make `itemsList` part of the model using an observable array...

```
 function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;    
    self.itemsList = ko.observableArray(itemsList);  
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();   
 };
```

..this works, but forces me to override `toJSON()` for each entity to suppress serialization of all observable arrays not part of the desired output json.

Another option is to add all arrays to the global scope:

```
  <script>
     var itemsList = ["one", "two", "three"];
     var anotherList = ...
  </script>
```

..this is risky, and frankly, it gives me hives; I don't prefer it; I'm assuming there' a better alternative?

I reviewed knockout's binding context [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html), and based on my understanding, neither `$root` or `$parent` can access scope beyond the root model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything you want to serialize into a sub-model and call `toJSON()` on it instead of the root model. Then you can put `itemsList` into the root model and access it from bindings.

Comment: Not a bad idea; it's only one field to add, I can use `$root.lists.listName` from anywhere in the view, just confirmed, works great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ko, but I think this should work:

```
<select data-bind='options: KoRepos.itemsList,                                      
                   value: selectedItem'>
</select>


 var KoRepos = {};  //Container for 'global' data repositories

 $(document).ready(function($) {
    KoRepos.itemsList = ["one", "two", "three"];

    function ViewModel() {
      var self = this;      
      self.selectedItem = ko.observable();   
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

This way you don't pollute the global namespace, only one new var is added (KoRepos).

I hope this helps

Comment: Yup, this is along the same lines of ebohlman's answer, using the container approach, thx.